# A question about connection in jconsole

Tags: jconsole

Good Day!

Friends, when I am runing a SampleTest (written in java by [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html#UsageThreshold), simulating a deadlock environmentn), Jconsole GUI response that `being connecting to` *** (refer to SampleTest PID)
How can I use the jconsole to connect the application? thanks first:)

Answer (score 1):

Run your application with following java properties

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9005
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false

This provide the JMX port , Do the authentication disable , and ssl disable respectively.

Then go to directory where your jconsole jar resides.
command
**Jconsole local_or_remote_host:JMX_port**
This setting must let your jconsole to connect to the application.